# Can't use .contains() or .startsWith() in android studio kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android so bare with me..
Basically the title says it all and i found literally nothing on this issue, I get "unresolved reference" when using .contains or .startsWith, and i'm guessing many others that i don't know yet.

My kotlin version is 1.4.32, says it's the latest

-Worth mentioning that i went to the build.gradle file and changed "ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"" to "ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"" because it was showing an error in the IDE which said <module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.2.> And it was solved by doing the above according to a stackoverflow post.

-Also i get a massage at the top of android studio saying <some kotlin libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer kotlin compiler and can‘t be read>. it says to update the plugin but it is at the latest version..

I'm open to share any inforamtion.
Any help would be appreciated.. I'm really stuck right now.

build.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You should post the relevant piece(s) of code.

Comment: It is not much to post, When i type for example " "that's a string".contains("s"), i get an "unresolved reference contains" error, it may seem that i'm ignorant or lazy but i really don't have anything to show but this, i found NOTHING on it, literally.

Comment: Please add the code from `build.gradle` files, so we can see if your versions and plugins are correctly declared.

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro just did.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding kotlin plugins?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

[https://metapx.org/unresolved-reference-kotlin/#:~:text=To%20conclude%2C%20the%20unresolved%20reference,to%20declare%20in%20the%20code](https://metapx.org/unresolved-reference-kotlin/#:%7E:text=To%20conclude%2C%20the%20unresolved%20reference,to%20declare%20in%20the%20code).

Comment: `kotlin-android-extensions` was deprecated a few years ago and should no longer be used.

Comment: Doing so gave me an error when building the app: "Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\SecondProjecto\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:", tried deleting kotlin-android-extention, still the same error.

Comment: Can you add also build.gradle (app) in the question post.